# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Wireless Asus USB-N53 (rt3572sta) driver installation issue

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

My purchase of the Asus USB-N53 just came in today and I spent several hours Googling and researching drivers for this device. When I first plugged the device in it connected fine to my open system, WEP, DHCP configured access point. I opened Google Chrome and a few pages loaded, everything seemed fine. 30 seconds later... Boom! It disconnected and showed attempts to reconnect and asked for the WEP key and just showed a state of infinite connection time until it asked me for the password again. I'm using amd64 (64 bit Ubuntu desktop
12.04 LTS)

The official driver can be found [here](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/license.php?sn=5017) although I had no luck with it.

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b05:179d ASUSTek Computer, Inc.
```

uname -a

```
Linux Jake 3.2.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:16:45 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is the OP's answer, originally posted in the question.**

I must of done something wrong when I originally installed the latest drivers from the chipset manufacturers website. I tried reinstalling and did modprobe rt3572sta and waited maybe 10 minutes??? and I connected then I rebooted and everything seems to be working so far. What I did do before hand is unplug the device and typed into the terminal (once for every source I attempted to install):

```
cd '<directory of the driver source>'
make uninstall
make clean
```

Then I went into the 2.5.0.0 directory and installed that with

```
make
make install
```

Then I typed

```
modprobe rt3572sta
```

This was all in superuser. For those who don't know:

```
sudo su
```